# Is there a better way? Reading XML to construct objects

Tags: java, xml, constructor

This is my first attempt at making a Java application.  Eventually I'm going to use JavaFX to incorporate graphics.

My first step is to import configuration like data from XML files, to construct a collection of Tile objects.

```
public Tile (String name, String imageName, int type, int up, int right,
        int down, int left,int feature){

    this.Name = name;
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.type = type;
    this.sides.add(up);
    this.sides.add(right);
    this.sides.add(down);
    this.sides.add(left);
    this.feature = feature;
}

public static void ReadTileXML(){
    try {
        Element tileElement;
        String tileName = null;
        String tileImageName = null;
        int tileCount = 0;
        int tileType = 0;
        int up = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int down = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int tileFeature = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> sidesImport = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Tile> tileGallery = new ArrayList<>(); 

        Element channelElement = ((Document) (new SAXBuilder()).build(new File("src/Resources/Tiles.xml"))).getRootElement();
        List<Element> tileImport = channelElement.getChildren(channelElement.getName());

        for (int i=0; i < tileImport.size(); i++) {
            tileElement = (Element) tileImport.get(i);
            List<Element> tileAttribs = tileElement.getChildren();

            for (Element tileAttrib : tileAttribs) {
                switch(tileElement.getName()) {
                    case "Name":
                        tileName = tileAttrib.getText();
                        break;
                    case "imageName":
                        tileImageName = tileAttrib.getText();
                        break;
                    case "type":
                        tileType = Integer.parseInt(tileAttrib.getText());
                        break;
                    case "Count":
                        tileCount = Integer.parseInt(tileAttrib.getText());
                        break;
                    case "Sides":
                        sidesImport.clear();
                        List<Element> tileSides = tileElement.getChildren(tileElement.getName());
                        for (Element tileSide : tileSides){
                            sidesImport.add(Integer.parseInt(tileSide.getText()));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Feature":
                        tileFeature = Integer.parseInt(tileAttrib.getText());
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Malformed TileXML, unknown Element.");

                }
                Tile tile = new Tile(tileName,tileImageName,tileType,sidesImport.get(0)
                    ,sidesImport.get(1),sidesImport.get(2),sidesImport.get(3)
                    ,tileFeature);
                tileGallery.add(tile);
            }
        }
    } catch (JDOMException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

I feel that the process I'm using is a bit heavy handed.  Is there a better way to create Objects from the reading of XML?  Setting all of the variables for the object and then passing that to a constructor just seems messy.

Comment: Should I be returning the tileGallery ArrayList to the method that will be calling the ReadTileXML method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) which allows for deserialization from xml text to Java objects. Basically you take a regular Java bean with default constructor, add annotations to bind the properties to XM lelements and let the parser do ...well, the parsing.

A popular alternative is [Jackson XML extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) which gives similar capabilities with more ease of use

Comment: For good measure: JAXB (with annotations) is nice and easy enough.